# Is there a setting that allows php variables to be set in an included php script and then reused in the main file?

Tags: php, linux, windows, configuration

I have just checked out a project from an SVN and have tried to run the project on my local machine using WAMP and virtual hosts. I'm getting a lot of errors saying variables have not been declared and after further investigation have found that they are set in separate PHP files and then have been included into the page throwing the errors.

This works absolutely fine on live but not on my local which makes me think it must be a PHP setting. I've looked in the PHP.ini file but don't really know what I'm looking for.

There are two things I would like to know...

Firstly is there something I can adjust in my PHP.ini file to solve this and secondly, is it a good idea to have this setting(should there be one), as I have always worked with PHP variables, private to the page unless setting a $_SESSION variable.

Hope this makes sense to someone.

I should also mention I'm using windows and the server that runs the file is using Linux.

Thanks in advance

Comment: So the variables are declared in sepreate files which are included in the main file? This shouldn't be a problem. It could be that your localhost and server have different settings for displaying of errors, try `error_reporting(E_ALL)` and you should see the same errors on your webserver

Comment: @kingkero and `ini_set('display_errors`, true)` as it should be set to `false` on production server.

Comment: It would be nice to see some sample `include`/`require` calls. The paths might be important (relative? absolute?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my guess is: your local and remote server have two different include paths set. you can check that by looking at the output of [get_include_path()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-include-path.php)

then, check if paths are correct, you might want to check paths of these files 
are they in the same directory? if no, are the paths in include relative or absolute? and how are the paths defined? these info will help you to get your answer. no php.ini setting can probably help you here.